# clang-format noop .clang-format file

Tags: c++, c++11, clang-format

I would like to start using clang-format in a extremely big existing code base. Before I commit to any of the clang-format options I would like to make sure that they work well and setting all the right rules at once could be extremely overwhelming.

I am looking on how to make clang-format to do nothing - or noop (no operation) .clang-format from which I could start modifying it to enable rules one by one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

clang-format isn't designed to do this at all. It doesn't apply given rules one by one, it reformats the entire source file, virtually ignoring any of the existing formatting. The options themselves are merely to configure how it is doing things, not how many things it is doing.

Comment: Thank you, I left with the same impression from the documentation, but somehow hoped that I am missing something.

Answer (score 0):

Utilize a [configurator](http://zed0.co.uk/clang-format-configurator/) to come up with your style file.  You can even paste in your own code to see how it would appear.